# Config Typescript compiler

Tags: typescript

I'm pretty new to Typescript. Here is my project structure:

```
rootDir
   js
      // js files here...
   ts
      file1.ts
      file2.ts
      ...
   tsconfig.json
```

What I want is to compile **on save** typescript files in the `ts` directory to the `app.js` file and put it into the `js` directory.

P.S. I'm using Typescript 3.5.3

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "js",
    "rootDir": "ts"
  },
  "include": ["ts/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules/**"],
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

Then run typescript in watch mode with `tsc --watch --project tsconfig.json` to compile automatically on changes

Comment: So `rootDir` is the directory with typescript files and `outDir` is the directory with output javascript files, right? And, one more question, you are using relative path for the `rootDir` and `outDir`. This will be relative to the tsconfig.json file? And the last one ;) What means `--project`?

Comment: Why we need to use both `"rootDir": "ts"` and `"include": ["ts/**/*.ts"]`?

Comment: `rootDir` will set the relative directory structure for `outDir`, `include` lets you specify exactly what gets compiled. This is specified in the docs.

Comment: Yes, paths are relative to `tsconfig.json` which should be in the project route. `--project` lets you explicitly specify the `tsconfig.json` file, although it is probably not necessary when using the standard filename.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Look for 'outDir' and 'compileOnSave'.

This will create individual js files for each ts file.

To merge the compiled js into a single app.js file you may want to take a look at webpack.